# Install ubuntu on Apple powermac G5 computers

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install ubuntu using few ISOs. But some ISOs are not bootable, some are installing but interrupts the process at final quarter. What is the best way and best iso image to install ubuntu on POWERMACG5?

Comment: You need the powerpc flavor.

Comment: What is powerpc flavor?

Comment: The microprocessor in the Apple G5 was a PowerPC G5. Thus, you need a version of Linux that targets powerpc.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of **Ubuntu** that will run on PowerPC architecture is 12.04. But, if you want something more modern, the latest version is **Lubuntu** 14.04, which uses the LXDE desktop environment, so it would probably be a better choice because of the old hardware.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42662/discussion-on-answer-by-pixelspark-install-ubuntu-on-apple-powermac-g5-computers).

Comment: Ok dear friends, our management decided to install osx 10.5.8. The safari of this version is supports to our software updates of account system. Thanks for the support you all gave me.